# Entering \ll command to compile using LaTeX suite plug-in to MacVim

Tags: compiling, mac, vim, vim-latex

[LaTeX Suite Manual](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-compiling.html) says that

> In order to compile a LaTeX file, simply press `\ll` while editing the file.

I don't understand how I can enter this command. I tried switching to the Editor mode in MacVim and entering variations on `:\ll`, `\ll` and `:\ll/` but nothing works.

Comment: `\ ` stands for your `leader`, you can configure the leader in use with `let mapleader="<the symbol you want>"`, e.g. I use `let mapleader=","` in my vimrc. So when I edit a file, compiling would be done with `,ll` in normal mode.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks! Isn’t : the leader?

Comment: No, `:` starts ex mode in normal mode (opens that bar below where you can insert a command), the leader is a special key for some nmap bindings which can be easily configured to your liking. Another plugin example using your leader would be Nerd Commenter, which uses `<leader>cc` to comment out the currently highlighted block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

The `\` stands for your leader, which is a definable key in vim for special shortcuts. You can set your leader with

```
let mapleader = "<leader>"
```

in your vimrc with `<leader>` being a key (e.g. `let mapleader = ","`). The key sequence would then be `<leader>ll` in normal mode (e.g. `,ll`).